# Searching the occurrence of \

Tags: java, string, file

I have a `String` that stores a path.  When I print the path, it is like: `D:\UnderTest\wavtester.wav`. In this string I wanted to know the index of the last occurrence of `\` character (the goal is to *get the name of the file* represented in the `String`), so I tried to use the method:

```
int x = nameOfAudioFile.lastIndexOf('\');
```

But I get an error corresponding to this statement saying : `unclosed character literal`

- *What does this error mean?*
- **How can I solve this error?**

Comment: int x = nameOfAudioFile.lastIndexOf('\\');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\` character has special functions in character and string constant, so you need to escape it in order to write it itself as a character literal: `string.lastIndexOf('\\')`.

Acatually, in order to be portable you probably want to use `File.separatorChar` instead of an explicit character constant. That way you'll get `/` on unix instead of `\`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.File;

class FileString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "D:\\UnderTest\\wavtester.wav";
        System.out.println(fileName);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println("Name: \t" + f.getName());
        System.out.println("Path: \t" + f.getParent());
        System.out.println("Exist: \t" + f.exists());
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
D:\UnderTest\wavtester.wav
Name:   wavtester.wav
Path:   D:\UnderTest
Exist:  false
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Disclaimer

This is not an answer to your question, it is not even an answer to *the* question, but merely the best suggestion I can provide in lieu of knowing what the actual question is. ;)

Comment: I wanted `f.getName()` ! This method wasn't in my mind , so tried with `lastIndexOf()` . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another \. You're escaping the ' with the single \, so it you should look like; nameOfAudioFile.lastIndexOf('\\')

Comment: Ironically, I made the same mistaken in the reply! I had to escape my escaped slashes!